# Escaping space in OpenCL compiler arguments

Tags: preprocessor, opencl

I'm trying to pass arguments to the OpenCL compiler which have spaces within them, but I can't find how to get it to handle spaces correctly (i.e. not just interpret them as the start of the next argument). My code is like this:

`status = clBuildProgram(output_program, 1, devices, "-D OutputType=unsigned char", 0, 0);`

Obviously, this leads to a compiler error of

`Error in processing command line: Don't understand command line argument "char"!`

Does anyone know the correct syntax to make it understand that I want it to define `OutputType` as `unsigned char`?

Answer (score 3):

Even if this question is old, i still come across it from time to time. 
AMD's OpenCL toolchain still does not handle spaces in macros defined on commandline, while it seems to work with NVIDIA's by now.

The simple solution is to replace all spaces with \t.

Tabs count as whitespace to the compiler, yet do not count as token-seperator to the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the command line space handling, it is not (at least on recent NVIDIA platforms) working as a standard Unix (or at least Windows) commandline should.

I've tried putting many braces, including `\' \" \\" \\'` and the backtick `` ` ``. I've even tried escaping the space itself (`-D OutputType=unsigned\ char`). This does not help, the command line string is probably simply chopped to tokens based on positions of spaces, and noone seems to care about braces.

One solution is to read the source code in a string, and prefix it with a single-line:

```
#define OutputType unsigned char
```

There is, however, one simpler solution. You need to include the following macro in your files:

```
#define MKTWOWORD(a,b) a b
```

And then you can use any of:

```
status = clBuildProgram(output_program, 1, devices,
    "-D OutputType=MKTWOWORD(unsigned,char)", 0, 0);

status = clBuildProgram(output_program, 1, devices,
    "-D OutputType=MKTWOWORD(unsigned,int)", 0, 0);

status = clBuildProgram(output_program, 1, devices,
    "-D OutputType=MKTWOWORD(signed,int)", 0, 0);

status = clBuildProgram(output_program, 1, devices,
    "-D OutputType=int", 0, 0);
```

The advantage is that you have to do string processing only on the commandline and not on the whole source code.

It's a bummer, but getting the MKTWOWORD macro inside the source code using the -D option is not possible, as it would result in a chiken-or-egg problem. You just have to include that in your kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to escape them with \" :

```
status = clBuildProgram(output_program, 1, devices, "-D OutputType=\"unsigned char\"", 0, 0);
```

?

Comment: Yup, and it doesn't work. I instead get the error

`Error in processing command line: Don't understand command line argument "char""!`

So it's still breaking it into two parts.

Comment: Strange, maybe a bug/limitation of your driver. Can you use uchar instead as a workaround ?

Comment: I can, yes. But I'm just going to use a find-and-replace function to mangle the source before I compile it instead, since the OpenCL preprocessor seems a little flaky. Easy enough to implement with `boost::algorithm::replace_all`.